# How can i parse JSON with multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

maybe i'm missing something here but i am trying to parse this JSON script:

```
JSON_DATA:
{
"Frontpage":[{"Id":"1","C_Page":"Frontpage","C_Code":"Title","C_Output":"A12-VEG"},
{"Id":"2","C_Page":"Frontpage","C_Code":"Welkom","C_Output":"Welkom A12-VEG"},
{"Id":"3","C_Page":"Frontpage","C_Code":"intro","C_Output":"hiiii"}],
"About":[{"Id":"5","C_Page":"About","C_Code":"Title","C_Output":"About"}],
}
```

array 1: Frontpage
array 2: About

i a'm trying to parse it like this:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(JSON_DATA).Frontpage,function(i,post){
    var id = "#" + post.C_Page + "_" + post.C_Code;
    $(id).append(post.C_Output);
    console.log('Added: ' + id)
});
```

if i remove About from the JSON data this script works. but i need more arrays...

i am going to try this:

```
{
"Frontpage":[{"Id":"1","C_Page":"Frontpage","C_Code":"Title","C_Output":"A12-VEG"},
{"Id":"2","C_Page":"Frontpage","C_Code":"Welkom","C_Output":"Welkom A12-VEG"},
{"Id":"3","C_Page":"Frontpage","C_Code":"intro","C_Output":"hiiii"}]
},
{
"About":[{"Id":"5","C_Page":"About","C_Code":"Title","C_Output":"About"}]
}
```

<< NOT WORKING

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line with the "About" array ends with a comma, making the JSON invalid since this is the last property:

```
"About":[{"Id":"5","C_Page":"About","C_Code":"Title","C_Output":"About"}],
```

Remove the comma and it should work.

Comment: i will try this now. i think this could be the problem!

Comment: @user3660885 What library produced that broken JSON? Complain to the author! If you created the JSON by hand, try using a library.

Comment: Hey Barmar, i did make the lib that produced the broken JSON... i use php to add up arrays and i put after every array a comma... but i need to find a way in php not to add a comma at the last array.

Comment: @user3660885 simple. Build a php array, and json encode it. **NEVER** manually build json, there's always a better way.